# Stop all subscripts if test fails

Tags: shell-script

Consider the situation:

**script files:** `main.sh`, `sub1.sh` and `sub2.sh`.

In `main` I call `sub1` and `sub2`. Then I am running `main` for all files from a folder, using `for`:

```
for file in samples/*.jpg; do bash ./main.sh $file; done
```

and it works very well.

But in `sub1` I am computing some values and I'd like to stop the execution of `main` for the current `$file` if the test fails, and start again `main` for the next file from the loop.

For example, if the folder contains jpg files `01,...,09` and the test in `sub1` fails for the file `04` then stop `sub1` for `04`, skip `sub2` for `04`, stop the rest of `main` for `04` and start `main` for `05`.

The test is:

```
if (( $numcc % 3 == 0 ))
then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Simply `kill`ing the processes would be an option?

Comment: @phk, well, I don't know the options. I just want to write some info on a log file inside the `else` condition and then stop everything and move to next step on the loop. Where should I `kill`?

Comment: How about 1) Set an flag and put an `exit` in `sub1` after the test fails and 2) Check the flag before invoking `sub2`? The loop structure should automatically make `main` to start with `05`.

Comment: @Barun, I understand the idea. Let me try to insert that. Should be inside the `else` or after `fi`? Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur, Let me post some example code in this regard.

Comment: @Barun, thanks so much. Let me study the code you proposed. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three sample scripts, `main.sh`, `sub1.sh`, and `sub2.sh`, are shown below. They are invoked as mentioned in the post, i.e.,
`for file in samples/*.jpg; do bash ./main.sh $file; done`

The basic idea is that `sub1.sh` creates a temporary file if the test fails; `sub2.sh` checks the existence of that file. Finally, the lock file is removed in `main.sh` every time before the other two scripts are invoked. Please note that this is *not* the recommended way to deal with temporary files, but just to illustrate the usage.

To simulate the test, I have checked whether or not a random integer is even. Replace your actual test conditions there.

The contents of `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export LOCK_FILE=sub1_failed.txt

echo "$0 $1"

[ -f "$LOCK_FILE" ] && rm "$LOCK_FILE"

bash ./sub1.sh "$1"
bash ./sub2.sh "$1"
```

The contents of `sub1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$0 $1"

if (( $RANDOM % 2 == 0 ))
then
    # Test failed
    echo "> $0 failed: Creating $LOCK_FILE ..."
    touch "$LOCK_FILE"
else
    # Test successful
    :
fi
```

The contents of `sub2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$0 $1"

if [ -f "$LOCK_FILE" ]
then
    echo 'Skipping sub2.sh'
    exit 1

else
    echo 'Executing sub2.sh as usual'
fi

echo 'sub2.sh done'
echo ''
```

Sample output from one of the execution instances is shown below. Due the nature of `$RANDOM`, the output would be different every time you run the above code.

```
./main.sh samples/01.jpg
./sub1.sh samples/01.jpg
> ./sub1.sh failed: Creating sub1_failed.txt ...
./sub2.sh samples/01.jpg
Skipping sub2.sh
./main.sh samples/02.jpg
./sub1.sh samples/02.jpg
> ./sub1.sh failed: Creating sub1_failed.txt ...
./sub2.sh samples/02.jpg
Skipping sub2.sh
./main.sh samples/03.jpg
./sub1.sh samples/03.jpg
./sub2.sh samples/03.jpg
Executing sub2.sh as usual
sub2.sh done

./main.sh samples/04.jpg
./sub1.sh samples/04.jpg
> ./sub1.sh failed: Creating sub1_failed.txt ...
./sub2.sh samples/04.jpg
Skipping sub2.sh
./main.sh samples/05.jpg
./sub1.sh samples/05.jpg
./sub2.sh samples/05.jpg
Executing sub2.sh as usual
sub2.sh done
```

Comment: The `sub1.sh` contains material after the test and I'd like to skip them also. Should I put `exit 1` before `else`?

Comment: When exactly would those material be executed? If the test succeeds? If the test fails? Or always? If you want to execute those materials if the test succeeds (with respect to the code in the answer), then simply put them inside the `else` block. Alternatively, you can also use `exit` as you have mentioned. However, to me it seems that can be entirely handled by the `if`-`else` blocks. You can try experimenting with this code -- place an `echo` statement at different positions and see what you get in output.

Comment: I put `exit 1` inside the fails part. So the `sub1` script stopped. Then I inserted the `-f` test in `main` to skip some other sub scripts and execute only the `echo end` line. I think I'm learning. It is working for a while.

Comment: @Sigur, Right! If relevant, you can altogether skip the invocation of sub scripts from `main` by checking the existence of the lock file.

Comment: Exactly what I did.